# If $y(t)\in L_2$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}\in L_2$, is it true that $y(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

My bad reasoning for why I think this might be true is that I know that some functions in L2 don't go to zero since they can asymptotically become "very jagged", so I was hoping that if the function $y(t)\in L_2$ had its derivative $\frac{dy}{dt}$ also in $L_2$, then that would mean that the potentially "very jagged" $\frac{dy}{dt}$ could not possibly integrate to a "very jagged" $y(t)$, which would mean that $y(t)$ would have to go to zero as $t\rightarrow \infty$ since it is also in $L_2$.

If this is correct, is there a good way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z(t)=(y(t))^{2}$. Then $z \in L_1$ and $\frac d {dt} z(t) \in L_1$. Use FTC to show that $z(s)-z(t) \to 0$ as $ s>t \to \infty$. So $\lim_{t \to \infty} z(t)$ exists. The limit has to be $0$ by integrability.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry I am a bit confused about how $\frac d {dt} z(t)=2y(t)\frac{dy}{dt}$ is in $L_1$, could you explain that part?

Comment: That is just Holder/Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. $\|fg\|_1 \leq \|f\|_2\|g\|_2$. @Minecraftdirtblock

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks!